# Why isn't my rename file working?

Tags: c++, io, file-rename

I am having trouble with renaming a file.  I'm attempting to delete several lines of an existing file, and replace it with the new one.

```
string line;   
ifstream myfile(filename);  
ofstream outfile;  
outfile.open(filename.append(".new"));  

if(myfile.is_open()) {
    //loop here that runs through code and calles
    //outfile << line; repeatedly
}

int test = rename(filename.append(".new").c_str(),filename.c_str());
if (test == 0) cout << "Success";
else cout << "Failure";
```

From what I have seen online, I would expect this to create the new document, fill it, and then replace the original with the updated one.

Does anyone see where I have gone wrong?

Comment: Are you closing your new file before attempting to rename it?

Comment: Note that (even when working as well as possible) this can/will fail in the presence of hard links -- when you "delete" the existing file, you only delete a link from the file name to the contents. Other names linked to the same content will still be linked to the old file, not the new one.

Comment: Are you running on Windows?  If so, you need to make sure to close any open handles to the old files before performing the rename, otherwise it will fail with `ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION`.  Or alternatively, open the files with compatible sharing modes, but that requires abandoning the C++ `iostream` API in favor of functions like [`_fsopen()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8f30b0db.aspx) or the raw system call [`CreateFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @JerryCoffin I wouldn't necessarily consider that a failure. It can, in certain circumstances, be a very valid and useful butt-saving semantic. It is definitely, though, something to be aware of, depending on what exactly the bigger context is...

Answer (score 4):

It looks like it is failing because you still have both files opened. You most likely cannot rename the file while it is locked. Close the file before attempting to rename it.

In addition, you'll need to delete the original file before you can rename.

In pseudo code this is what you need to do:

- Open original file.
- Open temporary .new file.
- Perform whatever task you do.
- Close both files.
- Delete original file.
- Rename.

It's likely that your C++ implementation will set `errno` when a call to `rename` fails. You should therefore check the value of `errno` to find out why the call fails. Do familiarise yourself with error reporting mechanisms so that you can diagnose problems yourself.

Comment: Alright, I included

    myfile.close();
    outfile.close();
    remove(filename.c_str());
    rename(filename.append(".new").c_str(),filename.c_str());

Now when I check my directory there is no ".new" file, just the unchanged original.

Comment: So, write something different to the file! Looks like you are just copying it in your loop. Also, the question was about why the call to rename failed. And I think I surely answered that.

Comment: I am writing something different to the file. I am deleting several lines from it, I just didn't want to clutter up my post with the specifics of the conversion since this is probably just a problem with the rename file. And the rename still fails, despite closing both files and supposedly removing the original.

Comment: If you close all open file handles to the original file, then the remove will work. If you close all open file handles to the new file, then the rename will work. I guess there's something amiss in your code. Of course, I cannot see your code now. I do suggest you follow the advice in my final paragraph and ask the runtime what the problem is.